# NodeJS + Mongo - How can I interact with my DOM fetching data from database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have a little express + ejs application which saving data of registered users.
Each user has a "role", which is saved in the DB.
Each user has an html div, and I want each div's color to be depended on the user's role.

Basically, I need to add specific class to each div with switch / case function.
I tried to understand how can I interact between NodeJS + Mongo + DOM the best way, but I have no clue.

- The role that is saved in the DB can't be equal to the name of his suitable class.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: AJAX is the glue you need.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at HTML Fetch API, the Async Await functions and Promises. Watch some videos on these topics and it will be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a helper function called `getColorByRole.js` like :

```
module.exports =(role)=>{
    let colorClass;
    switch(role){

      case 'user':
      colorClass='bg-primary';
      break;

      case 'manager':
      colorClass='bg-warning';
      break;

      case 'admin':
      colorClass='bg-success';
      break;

      default:
      colorClass='bg-light';
      break;

    }
    return colorClass;
}
```

Now when user request , call this helper function , send

```
let getColorByRole=require('./helpers/getColorByRole.js');

app.get('/dashboard',(req,res)=>{
      let colorClass=getColorByRole(req.user.role);
      res.render('/dashboard',{data:someyourdata,colorClass:colorClass});
});
```

now in frontend side , simply add colorClass to your div using EJS variable ,

```
<div class="<%=colorClass%>" style="width:100%;">
 Dashboard
</div>
```

update : if you are fetching multiple users ,and want to display diffrent color according to user role then do like this way :

```
User.find({},(err,users)=>{
    if(!err && users){
        users.map((user)=>{
            user.colorClass=getColorByRole(user.role);
            return user;
        });
    }
});
```